# Increase a value under loop in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop

I have this array, of which I defined few vectors and angles using numpy.

I want to change the third array element of O4, H5 and H6 as mentioned by +- 0.05 unit until the np.linalg.norm(vec14) reaches 6. Since, two of the three elements are negative, I used two dr and dq.

So, upon changing the third array element, the vector norm and cosine angle should change accordingly.

Upon running the code, I get only the initial value which are being printed without stop. I have to stop it forcefully.
Any help?

One additional question: Any help to write the data on a csv file? I tried, but the output shows "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

````
import numpy as np
O1 = np.array([-1.50038497e+00, -4.38065793e-02,  4.81288047e-03])
H2 = np.array([-1.82038214e+00,  8.59029461e-01, -1.66180895e-02])
H3 = np.array([-5.40667862e-01,  5.43751807e-02,  8.96204700e-05])
O4 = np.array([ 1.42268215e+00,  3.89704707e-02, -4.50889953e-03])
H5 = np.array([ 1.79930376e+00, -3.99409589e-01,  7.61615480e-01])
H6 = np.array([ 1.79494646e+00, -4.37242499e-01, -7.49911410e-01])
vec14 = O1-O4
vec12 = O1-H2
vec25 = H2-H5
cos412 = (np.dot(vec12,vec14) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec14)))
cos125 = (np.dot(vec12,vec25) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec25)))
#g = open ("test_array_manipulate.csv", "w")
while np.linalg.norm(vec14) <= 6:
    print ("vec14, cos412 and cos125", np.linalg.norm(vec14), cos412, cos125)
   #g.write ("%2.7f, %2.7f, %2.7f \n" % (np.linalg.norm(vec14)), cos412, cos125)
    dr = -0.05
    dq  = 0.05
    O4[2] = O4[2] + dr
    H5[2] = H5[2] + dq
    H6[2] = H6[2] + dr```
````

Comment: Which is your actual question? Please ask one at a time.

Comment: The value of `vec14` never changes in the loop. Of course it's going to go on forever. You need to put the `vec14 = O1-O4` into the loop.

Comment: I am sorry for putting multiple questions. Again, what I meant that I will keep the maximum  np.linalg.norm(vec14) = 6 means the maximum distance between the point 1 and 4. I thought if I can change this value upon changing the coordinate of 4th point. Is it totally unrealistic what I have done, or it could be performed? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The difference computes a new array. You need to keep doing that for the loop condition to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the while loop. The program changes the elements of the O4[2] but can not put them within the while loop. The better version will be,

````
O1 = np.array([-1.50038497e+00, -4.38065793e-02,  4.81288047e-03])
H2 = np.array([-1.82038214e+00,  8.59029461e-01, -1.66180895e-02])
H3 = np.array([-5.40667862e-01,  5.43751807e-02,  8.96204700e-05])
O4 = np.array([ 1.42268215e+00,  3.89704707e-02, -4.50889953e-03])
H5 = np.array([ 1.79930376e+00, -3.99409589e-01,  7.61615480e-01])
H6 = np.array([ 1.79494646e+00, -4.37242499e-01, -7.49911410e-01])
vec14 = O1-O4
vec12 = O1-H2
vec25 = H2-H5
cos412 = (np.dot(vec12,vec14) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec14)))
cos125 = (np.dot(vec12,vec25) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec25)))
while np.linalg.norm(vec14) <= 6:
    vec14 = O1-O4
    vec12 = O1-H2
    vec25 = H2-H5
    cos412 = (np.dot(vec12,vec14) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec14)))
    cos125 = (np.dot(vec12,vec25) / (np.linalg.norm(vec12) * np.linalg.norm(vec25)))    
    dr = -0.05
    dq = 0.05
    O4[2] = O4[2] + dr
    H5[2] = H5[2] + dq
    H6[2] = H6[2] + dr
    print ("vec14, O4[2] and vec25", np.linalg.norm(vec14), O4[2] , np.linalg.norm(vec25))```
````